# How to prevent the current page from redirecting to another page when refreshing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, react-router

Every time I'll reload the Profile page, it will redirect itself to the Homepage. How can I fix this?

Once a user has successfully logged in, he or she will be directed to the Homepage. On the Homepage, there's a Profile Page. I can successfully load the Profile page, however, once I'll reload this, the user will be redirected to the homepage again.

```
    //custom hook
export function useAuth() {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsub = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => setCurrentUser(user));
    return unsub;
  }, []);

  return currentUser;
}
```

**App.js**

```
function App() {
  const currentUser = useAuth();
  const user = auth.currentUser;
  const navigate = useNavigate();


  useEffect(() => {
    const unsub = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      if (user) {
        // User is signed in, see docs for a list of available properties
        // https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User
        const uid = user.uid;
        console.log(uid);
        navigate("/Homepage");
        // ...
      } else {
        // User is signed out
        // ...
        navigate("/");
      }
    });

    return unsub;
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <Routes>
        
          {currentUser ? (
            <>
              <Route
                path="/"
                element={
                  <MainLayout>
                    <LoginPage />
                  </MainLayout>
                }
              />
              <Route path="/Homepage" element={<Home />} />
              <Route path="/Profile" element={<ProfilePage />} />
            </>
          ) : (
            <>
              <Route
                path="/"
                element={
                  <MainLayout>
                    <LoginPage />
                  </MainLayout>
                }
              />
            </>
          )}

          
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

If I'll `console.log(currentUser)` this is what it shows:

[image]

Also in: https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/smfsro/how_to_prevent_the_page_from_redirecting_to/

**With Protected Route:**

```
{currentUser ? (
            <>
              <Route
                path="/"
                element={
                  <MainLayout>
                    <LoginPage />
                  </MainLayout>
                }
              />
              <Route path="/Homepage" element={<Home />} />
              <Route
                path="/Profile"
                element={
                  <PrivateRoute>
                    <ProfilePage />
                  </PrivateRoute>
                }
              />

             
            </>
          ) : (
            <>
              <Route
                path="/"
                element={
                  <MainLayout>
                    <LoginPage />
                  </MainLayout>
                }
              />
            </>
          )}
```

**PrivateRoute**

```
import React from "react";
import { Navigate, Outlet, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

import { useAuth } from "../../Firebase/utils";

const PrivateRoute = () => {
  const currentUser = useAuth();

  // //   const !currentUser = null; // determine if authorized, from context or however you're doing it

  // // If authorized, return an outlet that will render child elements
  // // If not, return element that will navigate to login page

  // return currentUser ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/" />;

  let location = useLocation();

  if (!currentUser) {
    console.log(currentUser);
    return <Navigate to="/" state={{ from: location }} replace />;
  }
};

export default PrivateRoute;
```

Comment: It is because of your useEffect. You have declared `navigate("/Homepage")` in useEffect, the code inside useEffect runs each time you reload a page. So, on the page is reloaded, it runs you components and then useEffect is called, where the user is checked and if true (true in your case) it navigates to Homepage.

Comment: @SaiKrishnadas I moved the `navigate` to when the user has successfully signed in. Is the method for that already alright or do I have to create private routes for my `routes`?

Comment: Taking the code out of useEffect would work fine. But for authentication methods, using private routes is best and suggested.

Comment: @SaiKrishnadas I tried adding a private routes, but it did not work

Comment: Please add a codesanbox link so that I can help you

Comment: @SaiKrishnadas is it possible to connect my Firebase project to a codesandbox?

Comment: Yes! You could...

Comment: @SaiKrishnadas I'll try to recreate it then

Comment: @SaiKrishnadas For now, I added the protected routes in the post. I'm not sure how I can recreate the firebase project in the codesandbox

Comment: I think the issue is that you don't have a default `currentUser`, so it's always undefined when you first load the page. Add a loading state to make sure you've finished checking the user's status before doing anything else.

Comment: @Vicky for the protected route?

Comment: Yes! Since your private route is within your protected route and is only rendered when there is a `currentUser`, `currentUser` would've already been checked when your private route mounts

Comment: @Vicky I just want to make sure I'm doing it right. I should add a `const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false) and then where do I put the `setLoading(true)`?

Comment: Oh sorry, I take that back, you might have to do the same for both. I'm unfamiliar with Firebase, but you're using a custom hook so `currentUser` isn't shared between components. I'd recommend you use a context to handle this. I'll add an answer so it'll look a bit clearer for you.

Comment: @Vicky ohh thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue is that `currentUser` doesn't have a default value, so it's always `undefined` when you first load the page. You should add a loading state to make sure the user's status is checked before using `currentUser` to do any logic.

Note: I haven't run any of the code below so there might be some mistakes, but it's just a general idea for reference.

```js
export function useAuth() {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true); // checking the user's status
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsub = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
        setCurrentUser(user)
        setIsLoading(false) // finished checking
    });
    return unsub;
  }, []);

  return {currentUser, isLoading};
}
```

So when you're checking if the user is logged in:

```js
if(!isLoading && currentUser){
  // is finished loading and user is logged in
}
```

I also recommend you store `currentUser` in a context instead of using a custom hook, since custom hooks won't allow you to share the state between components and it will be mounted every time you use it.

Instead your hook can be used to get the value from the context.

Something like this:

```js
// store currentUser inside context
const AuthContext = createContext();

export const AuthProvider = ({children}) => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsub = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
        setCurrentUser(user)
        setIsLoading(false)
    });
    return unsub;
  }, []);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{currentUser, isLoading}}>
      {children} 
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  )
}

// read context value with custom hook
export useAuth = () => useContext(AuthContext)
```

It'll still be the same when you're using `useAuth`, only that it's getting states from the context instead.

```js
const {currentUser, isLoading} = useAuth()
```

***---Edit to question---***

Context is used to share data throughout the application, it's great when you need to use the same data in multiple places. You can store data and pass it down with a **provider**, and access it with a **consumer**. I won't go into the details, but you can read more about Context API here: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper

About how to use AuthProvider, normally you could wrap it like this in App.js

```
// App.js
<AuthProvider>
  <div>
    <Routes>{/* ... */}</Routes>
  </div>
</AuthProvider>
```

But in this case since you're using `currentUser` in App.js already, you'd have to update AuthProvider to HOC, and wrap it around your component

```js
// AuthContext
export const withAuthProvider = WrappedComponent => ({children}) => {
  // ... the rest is the same
}
```

```js
// App.js
export default withAuthProvider(App);
```

The reason for this is because context values are only accessible within the scope the provider is wrapped around. Without HOC, your provider is wrapped around your routes, which means the value is not accessible within App.js itself, but is accessible in MainLayout, LoginPage etc.. With HOC, however, since you've wrapped the entire App.js, it can access the values in AuthContext.

Comment: I'm really sorry about this. If I'll use the `AuthProvider`, how would I import and use it in App.js?

Comment: Thank you, I was able to use it, it's just that I'm still confused with the `AuthProvider`

Comment: @RavenousRed I've edited my answer, see if you have anymore questions! I previously missed a line in my original answer in the context part, so I added that too: `const AuthContext = createContext();`

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `AuthContext` to pass parent to child component like below:

```
import React from 'react'
import { createContext, useState } from "react";

const AuthContext = createContext({});

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [auth, setAuth] = useState({});

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{ auth, setAuth }}>
            {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
}

export default AuthContext;
```